# Python не получается сделать функцию

Tags: python, for

Я читаю детскую книгу про Пайтон Джейсона Бриггса. На странице 93 во 2 упражнение у меня не получилось сделать функцию. Мой код:

```
def moon_weight_calculator (weight, increase, year):
years = years + 1
for year in range(1, years):
    weight = weight + increase
    moon_weight = weight * 0.165
    print("Год %s, вес: %s" % (year, moon_weight))
```

moon_weight_calculator (90, 0.25, 5)

Код - ответ:

```
def calculate_weight(weight, increase, years):
years = years + 1
for year in range(1, years):
    weight = weight + increase
    moon_weight = weight * 0.165
    print('Year %s is %s' % (year, moon_weight))
```

calculate_weight(35, 0.3, 5)

Я много раз перепроверял мой код похож на ответ, но почему-то не работает. Объясните пожалуйста в чём и где ошибка. Ответ спайдера на мой код:

[image: Спайдер]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В параметрах функции вы передаете year а используете years это разные переменные.
У Вас не правильные отступы в коде:

```py
# +s в years
def moon_weight_calculator (weight, increase, years):
    years += 1
    for year in range(1, years):
        weight = weight + increase
        moon_weight = weight * 0.165
        print("Год %s, вес: %s" % (year, moon_weight))

moon_weight_calculator (90, 0.25, 5)

print("------------------------------")


def calculate_weight(weight, increase, years):
    years = years + 1
    for year in range(1, years):
        weight = weight + increase
        moon_weight = weight * 0.165
        print('Year %s is %s' % (year, moon_weight))

calculate_weight (90, 0.25, 5)
```

В вашем случае вы объявляете функцию но уже следующая строка идет с тем же отступом (не относится к функции).